# DBUS - multithread processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, dbus

I have a main loop in my program, which calls the `dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch` method.
I have some registered callbacks which are invoked when a message arrives. Within this callback, I am also processing the response and sending back a response. The problem is that sometimes it takes a lot of time, so it is probably blocking message receiving from DBUS.
Can I call `dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch()` on the same connection from more than one thread? Will it then be possible to receive new DBUS messages while the previous one is being processed?
Or is it a better idea to process responses in another thread than the main loop, on which the callback is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

you can call **dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch()** from multiple threads if  you have called the function **dbus_threads_init_default()** atleast once.
Instead a better approach is to have a single thread running dbus dispatcher and use a thread-pool to process the data from callbacks.
See [dbus_threads_init_default()](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusThreads.html#ga33b6cf3b8f1e41bad5508f84758818a7) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

By the document provided by freedesktop.org, you can.

But if you operate with same DBusConnection instance from different threads directly, eg. calling `dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block` in a thread while anothoer thread is blocking on `dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch`, the connection maybe work unproperly. According to official document, DBus connection will be locked when calling callback functions.[DBusConnection](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html)

In my situation, the `dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block` didn't return even if the return message was send to my process (I had seen it on `dbus-monitor`). Calling `dbus_thread_init` does not work at all.

Recently I used a delegate to send / receive / dispatch all dbus messages in one thread, and problem disappeared.

[A mail in mailing list of freedesktop.org](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2017-September/017306.html)